# isUrlAddressable issue: Not loading/not initializing doInit

Tags: aura

Trying to open an aura component or app on a tab in lightning using custom url button to launch and lightning:isurladdressable. But the error says page isn't available.

```
<aura:component controller="ACRCloneActionCompController" implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<!--code here-->
</aura:component>
```

custom url launched on via custom button is: /lightning/cmp/c__acrCloneActionComp?c__acctid={!Account.Id}

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefix `c__` to component name and all attributes without which lightning will not recognize it (its namespace).

If your component name is exactly `acrCloneActionComp` the:

```
/lightning/cmp/c__acrCloneActionComp?c__acctid={!Account.Id}
```